# question on binomial theorem?

Tags: probability

Use the binomial theorem to show the identity for any $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, \cdots$

$$\sum_{m=0}^n \,^nC_m = 2^n$$

I know what the binomial theorem is, it has something to do with Pascal's triangle and being able to quickly find values for $\,^nC_r$, but can someone explain what the question is asking me to do?

Comment: The sum in question is the total of the numbers in row $n$ of Pascal's triangle.  If you think of how Pascal's triangle is generated you will see that the total doubles from one row to the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{m=0}\binom{n}{m} = \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+.........+\binom{n}{m}$

$\bf{Combinational\; Proof::}$ Considering a group of $n$ person from which a subgroup of some

person is to be formed. This Subgroup may have $0$ person, $1$ person, $2$ person ans so on.

Thus the number of ways of forming Subgroup is $\displaystyle \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+.........+\binom{n}{m}$

Now all these are covered if we note that each person can be in $2$ ways, He is either in the group

or not in the group which will form $2^{n}$ Selections

Thus $\displaystyle \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+.........+\binom{n}{m} = 2^{n}.$

Answer (score 2):

Put $x=1$ into $$(1+x)^n=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}C_n^kx^k$$ and you would get what you need

Comment: $\binom nk$ is less ambiguous than the various $C$ forms.

Comment: yea but can you explain what that means in words? how can just putting (1+x)^n be the answer?

Comment: @idknuttin: When $x=1$ then $(1+x)^n = 2^n$, and  $\sum_{k=0}^n \,^nC_kx^k$ becomes $\sum_{k=0}^n \,^nC_k$